# Calculate n where a^n mod m = 1?

Tags: c++, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

What is fastest way to calculate the first n satisfying the equation

> a^n mod m = 1

Here a,n,m can be prime or composite
mod : is the modulus operator

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not math homework.


Comment: I need to calculate this using code. I tried to brute force but it is not working within a given time limit

Comment: If this is a question on the "fastest" way to do this as far as CPU time goes, perhaps this question would belong here, but as is, this doesn't seem to be a good fit.

Comment: It is a part of a programming question

Comment: Yes, then define "best" as most performant, or fastest.

Comment: @user1640967 show what you have tried.  for example, [did you try a brute force like my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19526107/1583175)

Comment: This is a specialized case of the [Discrete Logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) problem, so I would start by looking into solutions to that problem.

Comment: a^0 mod m = 1 for all m>1 :)

Comment: sry, forgot to tell n>=1

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with the direct way:

```
int mod_order(int m, int a) {
    for(int n = 1, an = a; n != m; n++, an = an * a % m) if(an % m == 1) return n;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I have tried brute force. 2<m<10^7, 0<a<10^5 and I need to calculate this for 3oo test cases in 1 sec. This is not working

Comment: @user1640967 is it running too slow?  If so, how large is `m`, how long does the brute force take, and how long do you expect it to take?

Comment: I wanted to know is there any better mathematical solution to the above problem

Comment: This is related to the discrete logarithm problem, which is known to be in NP but highly suspected not to be in P.  There are algorithms which do improve the performance, but they are still slow (instead of taking O(m), they take O(sqrt(m)) which is still pretty slow)

Answer (score -1):

1. If gcd(a,m)>1, then there is no such n. (Obvious)
2. Otherwise, if m is prime, n=m-1. ([Proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem))
3. Otherwise (and as more general case), n=ф(m), where ф is Euler's totient function. ([Proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem))

As you can see, computing ф(m) is essentially the same as factorization of m. This can be done in sqrt(m) time or faster, depending on how convoluted is the algorithm you use. Simple one:

```
int phi(m){
  if(m==1) return 1;
  for(int d=2; d*d<m; ++d){
    if(m%d != 0) continue;
    int deg = 1; long acc=1;
    for(; m%(acc*d)==0; ++deg) acc*=d;
    acc /= d;
    return phi(m/acc)*acc*(d-1)/d;
  }
  return m-1;
}
```

Upd: My bad. a^(ф(m)) = 1 (mod m), but there can be lesser value of n (for a=1, n=1, no difference what m is; for a=14, m=15, n=2). n is divisor of ф(m), but efficiently computing least possible n seems to be tricky. Task can be divided, by using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) theorem (minimal n is least common multiple for all degrees for respective remainders). But when m is prime or has big enough prime divisor, and there is only one a (as opposed to computing n for many different a with the same m), we're kind of out of options. You may want to look at [1](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~math418/m418oh/m418og09.pdf), [2](http://www.mymathforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=36577).